# Does this sentence ever make sense?

Tags: limits, functions, definition

I was reading a paper and I found the following statement:

> Since $f(t)$ is non-negative and non-decreasing over $t$, then there must exists $a$, $0\leqslant a\leqslant +\infty$, such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=a$.

I tried to understand what does it mean but I am only able to say that it is useless. Am I right? I mean, $a$ could be anything (including $\infty$). So the limit could be anything too.

Comment: Well, it can't be "anything", since it can't be negative. The conclusion also says that a limit exists and that it is unique.

Comment: Ok, a positive function can't have a negative limit, right? The limit exists if $a\neq\infty$, no?

Comment: so as per @BernardMassé the statement's just saying that such a function must have a limit, not that all such functions have the same limit. You could construct a function of this type to hit any non-negative limit $a$ (including $\infty$), in the case of *this* specific $f(t)$ all it's saying is that it has to have a non-negative limit, somewhere...

Comment: We can also say that if $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\infty$, the limit exists.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but the meaning is: There exists an extended real number $a$ such that $a \in [0,\,+\infty]$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}f(t) = a.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the key point is that they are ruling out the situation where $\lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} f(t)$ doesn't exist. So the function can't behave like  $2 + \sin(t)$, which  isn't non-decreasing and fails to have a limit as $t \rightarrow +\infty$.

The fact that the limit is positive seems, to me, like a minor point in comparison.